# Rounding numbers by removing/truncating zero's

Tags: java

I have an issue where i am getting values like this. `"0.5"` and `1.0`

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(d).setScale(1, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
d = bd.doubleValue();
```

If i get the value as 0.5, i need to display as it is. But when i am getting 1.0, i need to display it as `1 instead of 1.0`. If i alter my setScale(0), i would get 0 instead of 0.5.

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.0");
df.format(0.912385);
```

I tried with decimal format too for the sa,e

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adjust the pattern so that it suppresses non significant digits after the decimal point

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do by [DecimalFormat(String pattern);](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#DecimalFormat%28java.lang.String%29)

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
df.format(0.912385);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
myBiDecimal.stripTrailingZeros()
```

However, beware that this will turn `10` into `1e+1`

Answer (score 0):

```
if(a % 1 != 0) System.out.println("Is a decimal" + yournumber)
else System.out.Println("Is not a decimal" + (int) yournumber)
```